# How to display inner child Boolean values a checkbox based on JSON structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing table based on JSON Data. I am able to get two levels, But I am not able to get most inner child values.
http://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/0n9fmawb/43/

```js
var data = {
"managment":
    {
            "Notice":{
            "Red color" :{"View":true,"edit":true,"delete":true} ,
            "Yellow color":{"View":true,"edit":true,"delete":true} ,
            "Specail color":" checkoxes"
            },
            "Black Notice":{"black":" Checkboxes"}
    },
"Faculty":
    {
        "salary":{"list":" checkboxes"},
       
    },
};

var zoneHtml = '';

for(var zoneKey in data) {
    zoneHtml+='<div class="zone">';
    zoneHtml+= ('<h1>'+zoneKey+'</h1>');
    var jsonData = data[zoneKey];
    for(var listUI in jsonData) {
        zoneHtml+='<div class="jsonData">';
        zoneHtml+=('<h2 class="prop">'+listUI+'</h2>');
        var ports =  jsonData[listUI];
        zoneHtml+='<ul class="port">';
        for(var port in ports) {
            zoneHtml+=('<li>'+port+':'+ports[port] +'</li>');
        }
        zoneHtml+='</ul>';
        zoneHtml+='</div>';
    }
    zoneHtml+=('</div>');
}


$("#zone").html(zoneHtml);
```

```css
.jsonData{
margin-left:10%;
}
.port{
margin-left:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zone"></div>
```

**Expacted Output:**

**I am attaching exacted output as a screen shot:**
[image]

When I am trying to put inner object **"red color"** three fields "delete", "enable", "view", Then it is showing object like below:

> Red color:[object Object]

First I want to get inner object value after that I will put checkbox. Thanks in advance. Your answer is valuable guys:

Comment: You are inserting Objects into Strings, that makes JS use `Object#toString`, which is always `[object Object]`. What do you want to be displayed there?

Comment: Please use camel case, dashes, or underscores for you JSON object properties, but it won't resolve your issue.

Comment: @Luca Thanks for the quick comment. I want to get true as marked checkbox.

Comment: I attached screen shot as a expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if property is an object, then you need to loop through each property again. You can play with your logic and make as a recursion function.
I have updated your logic:

```js
var data = {
"managment":
    {
            "Notice":{
            "Red color" :{"delete":true,"enable":true,"view":true} ,
            "Yellow color":{"delete":true,"enable":true,"view":true},
            "Specail color":" checkoxes"
            },
            "Black Notice":{"black":" Checkboxes"}
    },
"Faculty":
    {
        "salary":{"list":" checkboxes"},
       
    },
};

var zoneHtml = '';

for(var zoneKey in data) {
    zoneHtml+='<div class="zone">';
    zoneHtml+= ('<h1>'+zoneKey+'</h1>');
    var jsonData = data[zoneKey];
    for(var listUI in jsonData) {
        zoneHtml+='<div class="jsonData">';
        zoneHtml+=('<h2>'+listUI+'</h2>');
        var ports =  jsonData[listUI];
        zoneHtml+='<ul class="port">';
        for(var port in ports) {
        if (typeof ports[port] === 'object') {
         zoneHtml+='<li>'+port+':';
          zoneHtml+='<ul>'
          for (var i in ports[port]) {
           zoneHtml+='<li>'+i+':' + ports[port][i] + '</li>';
          } 
          zoneHtml += '</ul></li>';
        } else {
          zoneHtml+=('<li>'+port+':'+ports[port] +'</li>');
        }
            
        }
        zoneHtml+='</ul>';
        zoneHtml+='</div>';
    }
    zoneHtml+=('</div>');
}


$("#zone").html(zoneHtml);
```

```css
$("#zone").html(zoneHtml);
.jsonData{
margin-left:10%;
}
.port{
margin-left:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zone"></div>
```

Please update the code as you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I update one fiddle. please check http://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/0n9fmawb/43/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, need one help. Could you please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096238/implement-header-for-the-custom-table-in-html-and-javascript